# CVSSv2 score of 10, but no CVSv3 score

Tags: cvss

We are working on our Vulnerability Management process and as part of that, I was going through the reports from our infrastructure vulnerability scanner. In the reports, I noticed that some of the CVEs does not have a CVSSv3 score, but they have a CVSSv2 score.
Eg: [CVE-2008-6536](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2008-6536).

What does that mean? Does it mean that if we are planning to handle our vulnerabilities based on CVSSv3 score, then we don't have to consider CVE-2008-6536? This particular CVE has a CVSSv2 score of 10, but it says 'Not Applicable' under  CVSSv3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVSS v3 was released [in 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerability_Scoring_System#Version_3) so vulnerabilities prior to that were only rated according to the then-current CVSS v2. Also, my guess would be that "N/A" in this context stands for "not available" instead of "not applicable".

Of course, you should consider CVEs prior to 2015.